# Android update ui quickness

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an instance variable `mValue` whose value is updated periodically with network requests. The new value is shown in a `TextView`. And a button, which when clicked, logs the current value of `mValue`. Say I have this piece of code:

```
private int mValue = SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE;

// invoked on the main thread as I am using Volley
private void onNetworkResponseReceived(String response) {
     mValue = getValue(response); // line 1
     updateTextViewToReflectChangeInValue();  // line 2
}

private void onMyButtonClick() {
     myLog(mValue);
}
```

Suppose `updateTextViewToReflectChangeInValue()` takes a long time to finish, is it possible that what I see in the text view is different from what I see in the log when I click the button?

What will I see in the `TextView` and in the log if I click the button after line 1 finishes and before line 2 starts?

Comment: I want to see if the code has a potential bug.

Comment: How fast can you click? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `onNetworkResponseReceived` function is executed on the main thread, then both lines 1 and 2 are guaranteed to execute before the `onMyButtonClick` handler is called.

Comment: So Android will queue the click when I click the button while the main thread is in `onNetworkResponseReceived()`, then run `onMyButtonClick()` after `onNetworkResponseReceived()` returns?